# Laravel 4 Eloquent Class not found

Tags: rest, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to learn a bit about Laravel4 framework, so I decided to setup a small restful connection with a mysql database using the

`php artisan controller:make ProductsController`.

Unfortunatelly after running the app I get this error message:

`{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Products' not found","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/shoppingCart\/app\/controllers\/ProductsController.php","line":14}}`

anybody knows how can I fix that ? thank's in advance.

Here is the relevant code:

1) my route:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{ return View::make('home');});
Route::resource('products','ProductsController');
```

2) controller:

```
class ProductsController extends BaseController {

public function index()
{
return Products::all()->toArray();
}
    etc...
```

3) model:

```
Class Products extends Eloquent{
protected $table = 'products';}
```

I've done also `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: You do you have your `Products` model inside your `app/models` folder and it at least has the `<?php` start tag?

Comment: Hi, thx for the reply I just realized that I forgot to add the file extension .php to the Products file.